# Error / Exception handling in AbstractBpmnActivityBehavior.signal()

Tags: bpmn, camunda

Errpr / Exception handling in `AbstractBpmnActivityBehavior.signal()` is not the same as in `AbstractBpmnActivityBehavior.execute()`. An exception being thrown in `execute()` is properly handled by creating an incident (task with async-before). For `signal()` this is not the case.

```
public class Example extends AbstractBpmnActivityBehavior {

    @Override
    public void execute(ActivityExecution execution) {
        throw new RuntimeException(); // creates an incident
    }

    @Override
    public void signal(ActivityExecution execution, String signalName, Object signalData) throws Exception {
        throw new RuntimeException(); // doesn't create an incident
    }
}
```

I think the reason is that while in `execute()` a job exists for `execution.getId()` but in `signal()` it doesn't. This has been checked with the following query.

```
Context.getProcessEngineConfiguration().getManagementService().createJobQuery().executionId(execution.getId()).list()
```

Am I doing something wrong or is it just not possible to automatically create a *failedJob* incident by throwing an exception in `signal()`?